# Unknown parasite identification request

Tags: parasites

Unknown parasite infestation. Came with an olive tree that is suffering badly from numerous items tha cause leaves to deform and discolor.

Infestation is also traveling to neighboring plants, such as a Chili and an Aloe.

Please See attached photo for identification.

TIA

[image: unknown parasite on leaf]